# why in nested interface loop we need not be give implemented method higher access privilege?

Tags: java

```
interface a {
    interface b {
        void m();
    }
}

class c implements a.b {
    void m() {
        System.out.println("hello1");
    }
}

class d extends c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c v = new c();
        v.m();
    }
}
```

in this example, it shows assign weaker privilege but instead of implementing a.b  , I implemented only a then it will give the output why is this happen ,what is the reason behind it??

```
interface a {
    interface b {
        void m();
    }
}

class c implements a {
    void m() {
        System.out.println("hello1");
    }
}

class d extends c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c v = new c();
        v.m();
    }
}
```

op "hello1"

Comment: Please indent your code as you'd expect to see it in your actual source code - it's *horribly* difficult to read at the moment. (Ideally, provide more idiomatic names to the typed involved, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are NOT implementing the `a.b` interface method `m` explicitly for class `c`.

In your first example, when you call `v.m`, `m` is being called against an instance of `c` directly.
Because you have an `m` method in `c`, the compiler is happy that you have implemented interface `b` for class `c`

In your second example, you are still calling `v` on `c`, but because `a` is an empty interface with no members defined, only a child interface, the compiler is happy again.

Comment: Does C# have `System.out.println`?

Comment: I was only viewing questions tagged c#. I also know java, python, C, VB... so didn't notice slightly different syntax

Comment: The question was tagged for all possible languages, I edited them out.